# Can i set the image of MKAnnotationView like that?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have the method:

```
-(void)drawStars:(MKAnnotationView *)yourAnnotation {
    UIImage * stars = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stars.png"];
    yourAnnotation.image = stars;
}
```

So, Can i use this method in the viewForAnnotation method? like that :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKAnnotationView * annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"spot"];
    .... some code here ...
    [self drawStars:annotationView];   

}
```

it works, but maybe it's wrong?

Maybe you have an advice how to use the other method in the viewForAnnotation with pointer on current annotationView, to change its parameters ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's totally fine to set it like that.

My only advice would be about the function name, something like `set AnnotationImage` sounds better than `drawStars` when you are not drawing anything.

Comment: Thank you! Pteofil, can I ask you one more question? The problem that I'm russian, and i translate my app to english language. Can you help me with some sentences?

Comment: I'm not an expert in English. I believe you could get better help here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/